# How to stop Jekyll from overriding Grunt's minified HTML files?

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, asset-pipeline, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

I'm using `Jekyll` to build a simple static website and `Grunt` to manage assets.

I'm trying to get [`grunt-contrib-htmlmin`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin) to minify my Jekyll templates. When I run `jekyll build` it takes my template files and places them in the `_site` directory. `htmlmin` then takes these html files and minifies them.

But once I run `jekyll serve`, the html files are overwritten with the unminified ones.

Is there a solution, or a better way of going about minifying them? I saw that [Yeoman](http://o.zasadnyy.com/blog/optimized-jekyll-site-with-grunt/) manages to minify html without any issues on Jekyll, but I can't figure out exactly how they do it.

My `htmlmin` settings in Gulpfile:

```js
htmlmin: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
            removeAttributeQuotes: true,
            removeRedundantAttributes: true,
            removeEmptyAttributes: true,
            minifyJS: true,
            minifyCSS: true
        },
        files: {
            '_site/index.html': '_site/index.html',
            '_site/it/index.html': '_site/it/index.html',
            '_site/fr/index.html': '_site/fr/index.html'  
        }
    }
},
```